# how to get stderr with python exclude stderr in code execution?

Tags: python, exception

As I can see here: [How to get the last N lines of a subprocess' stderr stream output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995095/how-to-get-the-last-n-lines-of-a-subprocess-stderr-stream-output) , we are get the stderr on program execution - It's not so good for me. I want to get the exceptions or errors, just when system don't have so much resourses(RAM or CPU) to run my program. How I can catch this one?

Comment: And the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4995342/100297) doesn't work for you?

Comment: Try using PIPE?  That way you can get one line at a time.

Comment: 2 Martijn Pieters, I want just get in log var - stderr outside of my program, but which tells me only about this program execution if I have no PK resources for execute it.
2 cdarke, how ?